# Why is Magik from the X-men Locked up?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

I've just read the Regenesis one-shot, and in it [Magik](http://marvel.wikia.com/Illyana_Rasputina_%28Earth-616%29) (aka Illyana Rasputina) is locked up on utopia. What gives? Is she a prisoner of Cyclops' or is she there voluntarily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She is a prisoner there, kept in the "X-Brig".  Having said that, she is also provided with opportunities to escape, i.e. demons from Limbo have attempted to rescue her, and she declined them so she is also choosing to remain there.

[image]
[image]

She's been imprisoned after endangering the X-Men by using them to pursue a vendetta against the Elder Gods in New Mutants.

[image]

She is released though, only under strict supervision and technological restraints as needed for missions - she is part of Cyclops' "Extinction Team", designed to protect humanity from extinction and hence improve their view of mutants.

[image]

We also see her released in the AvX event, where she lures Dr Strange into Limbo and duels him.

Comment: Dueling Dr strange in limbo is pretty badass, if you ask me.

Comment: Check out AvX #3 for the follow-up act, if you haven't already. :D  That's the main reason I knew most of this - I went "Who the hell is that" when reading the cross-over.